# How can I determine the location of a file on disk (sector/offset) on an NTFS filesystem?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

Are there any tools/utilities that can enumerate all the sectors on which a given file is stored?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: file recovery [satisfy char minimum]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ntfscluster` which is part of the `ntfs-3g` package on Linux systems can do something like this. For example:

```
$ sudo ntfscluster -F WINDOWS/twunk_32.exe /dev/sdb1
Dump: /WINDOWS/twunk_32.exe
    0x10 - resident
    0x30 - resident
    0x80 - non-resident
             VCN     LCN     Length
               0  1144261        7
```

LCN stands for "logical cluster number" which you'll have to convert to sectors or byte offsets using the "bytes per cluster" number that's output by `ntfscluster -i $DEVICE`.